# Mercurial commit reverts with "abort: edit failed: vi exited with status 1"

Tags: mercurial, vi

I like using vi/vim for may editing but since vim and mercurial don't place nice together.

When attempting to commit a change the command line exits with:

```
$ hg commit
abort: edit failed: vi exited with status 1
```

It appears vi always returns 1 on exit:

Example:

```
$ vi
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: What does `ls -l "$(command -v vi)"` show? Does `EDITOR=vim hg commit` work as expected?

Comment: 1. ls -l "$(command -v vi)" -> /usr/bin/vi -> vim

Comment: Wait… how have you been exiting vi? Not with `:q`?

Comment: Exiting from vi - :wq

Comment: The actual fix was EDITOR=vim (on Mac vi returns 1)

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack that solved the problem.

1. Create a shell file

   $ sudo vi /usr/local/bin/hgedit

   vi $*
   exit 0
2. Update ~/.hgrc

   editor=/usr/local/bin/hgedit

Comment: That's a handy workaround, but I'd recommend pinning down why your vim is exiting with a non-zero status. See, e.g., http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14497/why-would-vim-return-non-zero-exit-code-if-i-exit-immediately-after-opening

Comment: Mercurial uses vi as the default editor, so it must work. It is clear that you have to understand the root cause: why vi exits with non-zero, as @torek points out. Hacks are always a bad idea: you will pay the price later.